# Total array of line item values in liquid

Tags: liquid

I have an array of line items that I would like to output the total of all of the price attribute.

**JSON:**

```
 "lineItems":
[
    {
      "code": "000001",
      "description": "Product 1",
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": 30
    },
{
      "code": "000002",
      "description": "Product 2",
      "quantity": 2,
      "price": 10
    }
]
```

**Expected Result from above: 50**
*Workings: (1 x 30) + (2 x 20)*

Using Liquid, how do I output the desired result?

I tried something like the following, as I couldn't work it out.

```
{% assign totalX = lineItem.price %}
{{ totalX | join: plus }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{lineItems | map: "price" | sum}}
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.